# Cannot filter query by child object enum field in OData

Tags: c#, odata

I have ASP.NET Core WebApi and endpoint with enabled odata query. Endpoint returns `IQueryable<MyDataResponse>` when `MyDataResponse` contains many child objects and creates from `MyDataEntity` with LINQ Select field by field in endpoint.

Most of odata queries with `$filter` works fine. HttpGet queries with `$filter` by all fields, all `childObject/fields` and enums works good. Except `$filter` by `childObject/EnumField`, it's falls with 500 error:

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "traceId": "00-deecb3ed2db91a408a21b51f80bf95e4-96af3e47d32e8e4c-00",
    "errors": {
        "message": [
            "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried to pull out `childObject/EnumField` as parent field and it works! But i need access by `childObject/EnumField`.

Can you explain why it falls with 500 server error? And how i can fix it?

Comment: Where is the enum defined? If it's a private/protected enum inside the child object type, then the model binder probably can't convert the filter expression.

Comment: @Simmetric Enum defined in its own file and have public modificator

Comment: Then please post more information: the exact `$filter` expression, the stack trace and innerException for the exception, and the code for `MyDataResponse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out why the error is falling. But i found request which works correct - `$expand=childType($filter=EnumField eq 'EnumValue')`